# What is the best ssh client for windows?

Tags: webserver

What is the best ssh client package for Windows, that match key exchange with the remote  `openssh-server 1:6.7p1-5+deb8u3` ?

Comment: Why are you asking Windows question on Ubuntu site ?

Answer (score 2):

PuTTY is the best ssh client ever. 
 You can download it from the official website http://www.putty.org/

Note : you can Try WinSCP but WinSCP does not focus on terminal access, it has basic support for it.

This [Link](http://www.htpcbeginner.com/best-ssh-clients-windows-putty-alternatives/2/) will help you and give you many alternative of PuTTY.

Comment: Not really. It does not even support tabs.

Answer (score 1):

Putty is the best and easy to use.
Official website http://putty.org
Download and follw to the instruction below

How to Use PuTTY to Connect to a Remote Computer

Start PuTTY by double-clicking its icon. 
When a PuTTY Configuration window opens select Session (it should be selected by default) from the Category panel on the left. In the Host Name (or IP address) field enter the name of the computer you wish to connect to. In the Port field replace 22 (the default) with 31415. Make sure that SSH is selected under Protocol (it should be selected by default). Click on Open.
In the new dialog box enter your username and password.
Once you see the prompt, you are connected to the remote computer.

Here is the link to the tutorial: https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204404604/using-ssh-in-putty-